# Is it possible to see an erroneously dismissed dialogue again?

Tags: battle-for-wesnoth

In [Battle for Wesnoth](https://www.wesnoth.org/), while playing a campaign scenario, it's very easy to **accidently dismiss a dialogue** that game uses to build a narrative. One misplaced mouseclick (e.g. directed at a unit) will do.

I know it's possible to read [all Mainline Campaigns' dialogues](https://wiki.wesnoth.org/Mainline_Campaigns) on the wiki, but is it possible to make it somehow reappear in-game?